# Is it good practice to make a class abstract if I no other class in my application inherits from it, just for the sake of making it non-instantiable?

Tags: c#, oop

So far in my application all the abstract classes I have do get inherited by some child class.

However, now I came at a point that I have a class that I never want to be instiatiated, however this class will also not be inherited by any other class in my application. My question now is if it still good practice to turn this class abstract just for the sake of preventing instantiation?

Comment: Sounds like it should be a static class rather than an abstract class. Otherwise, how can you get an instance of the class if it can't be instantiated? How could you call non-static methods on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent a class from being instantiated, you should make it `static`.

An abstract class that cannot be inherited doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is why you want to prevent their instantiation. The idea of abstract class is to have a "general" class to be used as a base of other ones.

If you want to do that, that is correct, if this is not the idea, then you have to use another approach.

Static class are not a good idea either, they like as "global variables" but you can use them anyway if you take care.

My suggestion is to rethink what you want to do and to use the correct approach. Perhaps you need to organize them using interfaces.